# Send message to server if client is forced destroyed

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I have unity game and i want to send message when script is destroyed (which mean someone turned off game on X or something like that).

I tried doing that inside `OnDestroy()` void but message is not sent (i guess since it is not sent fast enough and script destroy before message is sent) so what is solution to this?

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("4");
    server.Send(msg); // server is Socket
}
```

Comment: I don't think theres such a thing as "its not sent fast enough" since `OnDestroy` is always called before the object is gone. On the other hand if you are using raw sockets, maybe show the code on the receiving end too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [monobehaviour_flowchart](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), you can use use [OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) to handle application exit event.

Note: If your target platform is **Windows Store Apps** , you should use OnApplicationFocus() event instead.